# Android AsyncTask with native code

Tags: android, android-ndk

with the premise that I have NO EXPERIENCE of C language, I would like to solve a problem that does not allow me to proceed with the publication of my app.

I have a native function that uses ffmeg for file conversion, which I call from Android by AsyncTask.

I need to stop the native function, and tried in several ways:

1) I created a function "deleteRutine" in C which resets all the variables. (not working)

2) I added into function of converting a boolean variable, and I set it to  false via a method from Android (not working)

What else can I try?
Any advice?

Comment: Solution 2 works if done correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by rui.araujo, the second method should work if implemented properly.

The boolean value you are passing from Android to a native function, print it and check whether it is getting passed properly or not. Mostly there might be a problem in your JNI method implementation because of which you code flag is not being modified.

Your code should be something like this:

```
while(FLAG==true)
{
     //Do Your task
}
return;
```

This should definitely work if implemented properly. I have used this in many similar situations.. If there is still some problem, edit your post and post the code snippet of the second implementation...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a cross compiled ffmpeg binary then the native method should return as soon as the conversion is complete. If needed the best way to stop it would be to send it a quit signal using: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html as it will properly finish/close the file it's converting.